# Jmeter "__StringToFile" not working as expected in distributed testing

Tags: jmeter-5.0, distributed-testing

Current Setup:

1. Apache Jmeter 5.4.1
2. JDK 1.8.371
3. Firewall- Disabled
4. Created RMI-Keystore
5. All IP-Address in same subnet
6. added "mode=Standard" in user.properties file
7. Executing From GUI

```
${__StringToFile(./testdata/job_id_${reporttime}.csv,${job_id}\n,,)}
```

Actual : Above function able to write data if master and salve are same but if master and slave are different then it's not writing

Expecting: Able to write received response data into csv based on specific required json property value